# Text Animation in flash timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, text

I need help with a adobe flash animation that i am working on.
It a ad animation
I am making a scene of using text to slide in but when i test it, there is not enough time to see teh text properly before it gets to the next scene.

unfortuenly i can upload a swf or the fla file/link on here but i hope you get what i mean?

but anyway the thing that i need help with is displaying text with a timer. And when the timer was up the text disapears or the whole scene disapears and move to the next scene. but with my text it is. At the start of the scene the text slides in from the edge in the center of on the top stay like that for... I don't know 4000 or 5000 seconds (in miliseconds 1000 = 1sec). I know that is a lot to understand but i need help with it please. Does anyone have an idea. 
Unfortenly  i don't know  actionscript really well. I need to learn it and also i am using Adobe Flash Professionl CS6. So can anyone please Help?

Comment: Please show us the ActionScript you have written and a screenshot of the animation’s timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With actionscript you can use a timeout function like this:

```
setTimeout(myTimeOut, 4000);
function myTimeOut():void{
    //your actions here such as:
removeChild(myText);
}
```

However, as @HarrySmart mentioned, you might be better off just controlling it with the timeline. Just add more frames the longer you want it to remain on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a simple task that doesn't require complex data updates, and you don't know AS3 at all, it might be better for you to use timeline animations.